# How to reference a user defined property in another Maven POM?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have two POMs that are somehow in parallel/do not extend each other. Is it possible to define a user property in one POM:

```
...
<properties>
    <the.property>This is the property</the.property>
</properties>
...
```

and reference it in the second POM? Something like this `${pom1.artifact.id-the.property}`...

Answer (score 0):

No.

You usually handle this by using a common parent POM.